# How to calculate voltages on guitar fuzz circuit with pnp and npn transistors?

Tags: amplifier, npn, pnp, guitar-pedal

I have built this circuit on a veroboard, and it seems to me that it has been wired correctly. I do however get a very low output from the circuit, approx 1/2 to 1/3 of the input signal. I reckon that either I've fried one of the transistors, or I've soldered in a wrong resistor somewhere.

I want to calculate the different voltages that I should be able to measure around the circuit, but I can't get my head around this particular circuit. If anybody could point me in the right direction to find the BE and CE current on Q2 I think I'd be able to figure the rest out myself. Thanks.

[image: circuit in question]

Comment: You're using germanium parts where it asks for them, right?

Comment: Maybe you have miswired it because the circuit schematic techniques are poor and could lead to reading the digram incorrectly. For instance, what do you have the base of Q1 connected to - please list all the components.

Comment: This circuit is not intended to be an amplifier, it's designed to introduce a certain kind of distortion. The germanium diodes at the output are going to limit the signal level to a few hundred mV, regardless of the input signal level. The idea is to mix the output of this circuit with the original signal to get the combined sound you want.

Comment: Spice it!  You can even take a recording of a riff and process it with spice and then hear what it would sound like.  I find that's a fun way to design guitar effects.

Comment: You can use "normal parts" (Si transistors instead of exotic Ge) to make a frequency tripler. 2N5087/5088 widely used for guitar circuits.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Yes, I know. But the circuit is not intended to cut the strength of my signal in half.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, I am using correct parts.

Comment: @Andyaka Its wired according to the schema. The base of Q1 is connected to C2 and R2.